# MVC5 Change controller name only without effect the actions inside

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

I need to change the name of the controller in MVC 5 I used to do the following:

```
[RouteArea("Dispatch")]
[RoutePrefix("TrackedAssets")]
[Route("{action=index}")]
public class TrackedItemsController : MainControllerBase
```

```
{
```

When i try to hit Index action its OK. 
But there are some actions for CRUD, when i tried to hit them by the new URL /Dispatch/TrackedAssets/Edit/47
It gives me:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Lynx/Dispatch/TrackedAssets/Edit/47

Below is the signature of the action:

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int? id)

  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult Edit
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requested route i.e `/Lynx/Dispatch/TrackedAssets/Edit/47` will not hit any action method since you have not prefixed your Edit action method with route attribute just like you have set route attribute for index method.

```
[Route("{action=edit}")]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
```

Try this and please mark this as answer if it helped you.